# substituting values in column under if-condition SAS

Tags: if-statement, sas, sas-macro

I am fairly new to sas and I am wrapping my head around this problem. I have two tables A and B.
The first one collects information about customers in terms of their purchases and the specific products they purchased

A

| Customer_id | product_code |
| --- | --- |
| 1111111 | 12345 |
| 1111111 | 34523 |

The second one is some sort of a dictionary, i.e. contains old and new codes, the old code being the key and the new one the updated version.

B

| old | new |
| --- | --- |
| 34523 | 22256 |
| 89765 | 76576 |

My goal would be to update in table A, all the references to old codes with their updated (new) version. In the end A should look like

| Customer_id | product_code |
| --- | --- |
| 1111111 | 12345 |
| 1111111 | **22256** |

The approach that I wuld take in this example is the following (pseudo-code)

```
if A.product_code in B.old then
   A.product_code = B.new
else
   nothing
```

But I am struggling a bit with sas synthax to implement that.

I really hope that my issue is clear enough and do not hesitate to ask further clarification if necessary.

Thanks to anyone who is willing to participate

Comment: Are those numeric or character variables?

Comment: Why would you want to change your existing dataset?  Shouldn't you be making a NEW dataset that has the new values for PRODUCT_CODE?  Why mess up your inputs?

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
data a;
input Customer_id product_code;
datalines;
1111111 12345
1111111 34523
;

data b;
input old new;
datalines;
34523 22256
89765 76576
;

proc sql;
   update a
   set product_code = 
      (select new from b
      where a.product_code = b.old)
   where exists (
      select 1
      from b
      where a.product_code = b.old)
   ;
quit;
```

Comment: thank you very much :)

as for the syntax being used:
`update a` (ok)
`select new from b where a.product_code = b.old` if a has an old code then update it
`where exists (...)` are you creating a boolean to tell if the product code is equal to the old code? Why is this step necessary?

Comment: @JacquesLeen A where clause restricts which rows get updated - i.e. only those rows needing an update.  The existential test is the least expensive way to find those rows

Answer (score 1):

A very SAS way is to use `MODIFY` statement and hash lookup.

```
data master;
  modify master;
  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    declare hash mappings(dataset:'code_changes(rename=new_code=code)');
    mappings.defineKey('old_code');
    mappings.defineData('code');
    mappings.defineDone();
    call missing(old_code);
  end;

  if mappings.find(key:code)=0 then replace;
run;
```

Another `MODIFY` way is to read changes with a `SET` statement.

This example requires an index on the master table.

```
proc sql;
  create index code on master;

data master;
  set mappings;

  reset = 1;
  do until (_iorc_);
    code = old_code;
    modify master key=code keyreset=reset;

    if _iorc_ = 0 then do;
      code = new_code;
      replace;
    end;
    reset = 0;
  end;

  _error_ = 0;
run;
```